# How to stop execution when form validation in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, cordova

I have two questions from the coding below.

First, now i would like to perform validation before submission. How can I stop submission if some errors are detected from the validation function? Is it simply return false after each of the error msg? however, it seems still check all fields instead of stopping after getting one error.

Second, i would like to insert the data via php. Everytime, it can successfully add the data to the database, however, it always alert "Error: error". I dunno where does the error come from...

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#test').click(function(){
    validation();   
    });

    function validation(){  
    var loginID=$("#loginID").val();

    if (loginID=="" || loginID==null)
    {
        $('#errorID').empty();
        $('#errorID').append(
        '<h6>' + "The Login Name cannot be empty" + '</h6>');
        $("#errorID").show();

    }
    else
    {

    }

    // check pw
    $("#errorPW").hide();
    if ($("#loginPW").val()=="" || $("#loginPW").val()==null)
    {
        $('#errorPW').empty();
        $('#errorPW').append(
        '<h6>' + "The Login Password cannot be empty" + '</h6>');
        $("#errorPW").show();

    }
    else
    {

    }

    //return false;

    } // end of #validation


    $('form').submit(function(){

        validation();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: 
            {
                    loginID:        $("#loginID").val(),
                    // some data here

            },
            url: 'http://mydomain.com/reg.php',
            success: function(data){
                alert('successfully.');         
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus){
                alert("Error: " + textStatus);
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: I am pretty sure the third parameter in the error callback is a string specifying what the error is. Try alerting that instead.

Comment: textStatus return "error" . the whole msg is "Error: error"

Comment: The function is defined as such `function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown )` does `errorThrown` have anything in it?

Comment: error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert("Request failed: " + textStatus + errorThrown);   i have tried this, and return "Error: error"

Comment: It still said `Error:` even though you changed it to `Request failed:` instead? Are you sure you saved your changes?

Comment: sorry. should be    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    alert("Error: " + textStatus +errorThrown);  and return Error: error

Answer (score 1):

you can use `return false`.It will stop the execution

```
<form onSubmit="validatdeForm();"></form>


function validatdeForm()
{
  //here return true if validation passed otherwise return false
}
```

or

```
 if (loginID=="" || loginID==null)
    {
        $('#errorID').empty();
        $('#errorID').append(
        '<h6>' + "The Login Name cannot be empty" + '</h6>');
        $("#errorID").show();
        return false;

    }

    if ($("#loginPW").val()=="" || $("#loginPW").val()==null)
{
    $('#errorPW').empty();
    $('#errorPW').append(
    '<h6>' + "The Login Password cannot be empty" + '</h6>');
    $("#errorPW").show();
    return false;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

it should be something like below. **return false** stop execution of script when error is there.

```
function validation(){  
    var loginID=$("#loginID").val();

    if (loginID=="" || loginID==null)
    {
        $('#errorID').empty();
        $('#errorID').append(
        '<h6>' + "The Login Name cannot be empty" + '</h6>');
        $("#errorID").show();
        return false;

    }
    else
    {
       return true; 
    }

    // check pw
    $("#errorPW").hide();
    if ($("#loginPW").val()=="" || $("#loginPW").val()==null)
    {
        $('#errorPW').empty();
        $('#errorPW').append(
        '<h6>' + "The Login Password cannot be empty" + '</h6>');
        $("#errorPW").show();
        return false;

    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }

    return true;

    } // end of #validation
```

Answer (score 1):

Design your `validation` function as below,

```
function validation()
{  
    var isValid = true;

    if(field validation fail)
    {
        isValid = false;
    }
    else if(field validation fail)
    {
        isValid = false;
    }

    return isValid;
}
```

basic idea behind `code` is to `returning false` whenever your `validation` fails.

Answer (score 1):

To make a proper form validation, I will suggest you go about doing it in a more organized way. It is easier to debug. Try this:

```
var validation = {
  // Checking your login ID
  'loginID' : function() {
    // Login ID validation code here...
    // If a validation fails set validation.errors = true;
    // Additionally you can have a validation.idError that contains
    // some error message for an id error.
  },

  // Checking your password
  'loginPW' : function() {
    // Password validation code here...
    // If a validation fails set validation.errors = true;
    // As with id, you can have a validation.pwError that contains
    // some error message for a password error.
  },

  'sendRequest' : function () {
    if(!validation.errors) {
      // Code for whatever you want to do at form submit.
    }
  }
};

$('#test').click(function(){
  validation.errors = false;
  validation.loginID();
  validation.loginPW();
  validation.sendRequest();
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function validateimage() { if($("#photo").val() !== '' ) {

    var extensions = new Array("jpg","jpeg","gif","png","bmp");
    var image_file = document.form_useradd.photo.value;
    var image_length = document.form_useradd.photo.value.length;
    var pos = image_file.lastIndexOf('.') + 1;
    var ext = image_file.substring(pos, image_length);
    var final_ext = ext.toLowerCase();
    for (i = 0; i < extensions.length; i++)
    {
    if(extensions[i] == final_ext)
    {
    return true;
    }
    }
    alert(" Upload an image file with one of the following extensions: "+ extensions.join(', ') +".");

    //$("#error-innertxt_photo").show().fadeOut(5000);
    //$("#error-innertxt_photo").html('Enter valid file type');
    //$("#photo").focus();
    return false;

}
```